# RestEasy Interceptor

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I wonder if it is as hard as I currently try to achieve it. I use Some Interceptor for security in my RESTEasy application. The interceptor implements `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter`.

I use such a code to access request data:

```
if (((PostMatchContainerRequestContext) requestContext).getHttpRequest().getHttpMethod().equals("GET")) {
   requestedId = Long.parseLong(requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().get("id").get(0));
} else {
   postDataMap = getPostData(requestContext);
}
```

and

```
private LinkedHashMap getPostData(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
   Object obj = null;

    try {
       String result = IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream());
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       obj = mapper.readValue(result, Object.class);
       System.out.println(obj);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
   return (LinkedHashMap) obj;
}
```

But it seams ridiculous to access request data in such a way. Now I wanted to access `DELETE-Request` data but couldn't find any solution. Is there a much proper way to achieve what I am currently doing?

Answer (score 0):

By intercepting you mean to check data before it goes to the rest layer? I have achieved this with implementing Filter interface (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

Hope it helps.
Br,
Dusan

Comment: yes, I mean what you've mentioned. I'll try your solution and give you a feedback.

Comment: Really useful example can be found http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you can set security info in header,get value like this:

```
String logintoken = crc.getHeaderString("token");
```